# Emitter follower time constant

Tags: bjt

How can I calculate the time constant to charge the capacitors for this emitter follower circuit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a non-linear time constant and also changes with supply voltage, temperature and transistor type. So, how keen are you to figure this out given that it will be of little use to you if someone managed to come up with an answer.

Comment: We can consider a fixed BJT and a fixed temperature. Supply voltage also is fixed and shown in the schematic.

Comment: What information do you actually need that isn't contained in the LTspice plot you made? What are you *really* trying to figure out? Even with all those things fixed, it's still a non-linear time constant i.e. one value will not fit all situations.

Comment: I would like to know the equation of the capacitor charge current/voltage vs time

Comment: That's easy, \$i = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ i.e. current equals rate of change of voltage multiplied by capacitance.

Comment: The effective resistance of the source charging the capacitors is roughly the parallel combination of R3 and R4, divided by the beta of the transistor. Assuming a beta of about 100, it works out to about 24 ohms, which agrees with your peak current that's on the order of 1 A. 28 V divided by 0.97 A would suggest an effective resistance that's closer to 29 ohms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, on the left is your original circuit. In the next one I have replaced parallel pairs of components with their single equivalents, and on the right is an approximate equivalent circuit, where the transistor has been replaced with passive parts:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB8bJF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've assumed the transistor to have a current gain of β=100, but of course that's very unlikely to be the case if you actually build this. That means the approximation on the right is very dependent on the particular transistor you use.

There seems to be no benefit to using a transistor in the role you have here, since a single resistor of 23.5Ω would do roughly the same thing. You could get rid of the the diode, too, and have the capacitors charge to the full supply voltage, avoiding the \$V_{BE}\$ drop of 0.7V.

Clearly, the time constant is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tau &\approx \frac{R1\parallel R2}{\beta}\times (C_1\parallel C2) \\ \\
&\approx \frac{2.35k}{100} \times 26.7\mu \\ \\
&\approx 650\mu s
\end{aligned}
$$.